# powershell cmd script of out-zip.ps1

Tags: command-line, backup, powershell, zip

i have found this powershell script online and i would like to run this from a batchfile. Can anyone give me the correct syntax for this script.
And if possible make it possible to input multiple directories the script wil zip.

```
########################################################
# out-zip.ps1
#
# Usage:
#    To zip up some files:
#       ls c:\source\*.txt | out-zip c:\target\archive.zip $_
#
#    To zip up a folder:
#       gi c:\source | out-zip c:\target\archive.zip $_
########################################################

$path = $args[0]
$files = $input

if (-not $path.EndsWith('.zip')) {$path += '.zip'} 

if (-not (test-path $path)) { 
  set-content $path ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
} 

$ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($path) 
$files | foreach {$zipfile.CopyHere($_.fullname)}
```

So what I actually need is the cmd file that says this (preferably with extra folders)

```
gi c:\source | out-zip c:\target\archive.zip $_
```

Thanks, Kim!

Comment: Is [this](http://stam.blogs.com/8bits/2010/06/create-zip-archives-with-powershell.html) where you found that example?

Comment: yes, among various other places

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with only a 1kb zip file being created. I found that I had do include a -noexit in the command:
powershell.exe -noexit -Command "gi c:\source | C:\users\Kim\Dpcuments\WindowsPowerShell\out-zip.ps1 c:\target\archive.zip"

Granted, this seems to cause some other issues when trying to use this in a batch file because it leaves powershell open. There are some other solutions out there that I'm investigating that will either just wait for a set amount of time for the "zip" to complete or that actually compares the source files with the completed zip file before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the PowerShell script file for you:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Zip up files and folders
.EXAMPLE
To zip up some files:
    ls c:\source\*.txt | out-zip.ps1 c:\target\archive.zip
.EXAMPLE
To zip up a folder:
    gi c:\source | out-zip c:\target\archive.zip
#>

param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,ValueFromPipeline=$TRUE)] $files,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,position=0)] [string] $path
)

if (-not $path.EndsWith('.zip')) {$path += '.zip'} 

if (-not (test-path $path)) { 
  set-content $path ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
} 

$zipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($path)) 
$files | %{$zipfile.CopyHere($_.fullname)}
```

Assuming out-zip.ps1 is saved to `C:\users\Kim\Dpcuments\WindowsPowerShell\out-zip.ps1`, below is the batch file you need.

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -Command "gi c:\source | C:\users\Kim\Dpcuments\WindowsPowerShell\out-zip.ps1 c:\target\archive.zip"
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, tried it but it doesn't work. It creates a zip file but it's empty.

Comment: @Kim are you trying to zip up C:\source or another folder?

Comment: @Kim you can lose the $_'s with my improved version of the script.

Comment: i am backing up c:\test and the ps1 file is in c:\backup\, this is my code:
powershell.exe -Command "gi c:\test | C:\backup\out-zip.ps1 c:\backup\archive.zip"

Comment: I have tried the code but it still returns a 1kb zip file (empty), did you manage a succesful zip?